# Why first_or_initialize try to save record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a simple association

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

And the following code

```
element = Element.find_or_initialize_by_name(elem_name)
element.categories = cat_names.map { |name| Category.where(name: name, element_id: element).first_or_initialize }
```

raises **ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace resources because one or more of the new records could not be saved.)** when cat_names includes a name already taken.

From my understanding first_or_initialize calls 'new' so no record should be saved. 
Is this an expected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when the Element instance is not found, rails initializes an instance of it which your "element" variable points to. Then, when you try to access the element's "category" attribute it throws the:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace resources because one or more of the new records could not be saved.)**

since the Element record was not persisted into the database (only initialized).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So if I save the element before accessing its categories, first_or_initialize should work "properly". right?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here `element_id: element`. Use `element: element` or `element_id: element_id`.

Your query `Category.where(name: name, element_id: element)` always returns empty.

And you initialize new category with existing name. As your model has validation `validates :name, uniqueness: true` you receive this error